# Online/Offline status indicator UI element for ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I want to add an online/offline indicator control to my ios app. I need to be able to programmatically set the status to offline (red) or  online (green). Will NSLevelIndicator support this usecase? Or should I go with a label. This seems like an easy enough ask, but could not find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by presence status indicator?

Comment: For iPad you'll want to use `UIKit` framework, not `AppKit`.

Comment: Presence status indicator is the green/red dot in IM clients that shows you are available/busy

Comment: I asked this question when I was very new at iOS programming. I have since figured out a way to do this (and many other things thanks to stack overflow). I use a circular view and link it's color to a local bool isConnected. When isConnected is set to YES/NO, change the view's color to green/red. I liked this approach better than using a UIImageView with different images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to place a UILabel or UIImageView within your app's layout (e.g. in your navigation bar, if your app has one).

Just as a side note: Don't aim for the status bar (if you meant the signal indicator). It's a mess to handle icon placement in respect to device orientation and other possible displayed icons. Besides this, there's a risk your app is being rejected by Apple, if you manipulate the status bar.

Comment: Thanks, I went with UIImageView and changed the image based on status.  That seems to be the way most people are doing it, given that it's not even documented anywhere :)